# Installing a dimmer switch for a ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan, fans, bedroom

I have a ceiling fan with a lights that have to separate switches- one to control the fan on/off, and another to control the lights on/off.  I want to put a dimmer on the light switch only but I most of what I have looked at warns against certain setups- I just want to make sure adding a dimmer switch for the light only won’t put the house at any risk. Can anyone provide some clarification? TIA.

Comment: Since you have separate switches, adding a light-only dimmer is safe provided that you use the correct type. Some dimmer is for incandescent bulbs only, while some are for CFL or LED bulbs. Also make sure the total power of your bulbs is below the dimmer's limit.

Answer (score 1):

### Dimming the lights only is fine here

The problem that you're being warned about is that a dimmer switch designed for *lights* will not have a good time of things if you hook a *fan* up to it.  Since you have separate switches controlling your lights and fan, using a dimmer with sufficient rating for the lights installed into your fan+light combination to control the lights will be fine.